# How to stop PHP from logging PHP Notice errors

Tags: php, logging

I'm trying to not log notice errors, which are being written to an error log file on my server.  I've tried (at the top of my `index.php`):

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);  
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

But I'm still getting PHP notice errors in said error log file.

I'm on a shared hosting environment, so I can't edit my `php.ini` file.

`phpinfo()` tells me:

```
- Version 5.2.12
- error_reporting 6143
- error_log error_log
- safe_mode Off
```

Comment: How about fixing the causes of the notices instead of closing your eyes to that? They don’t occur without any reason.

Comment: The causes of the notices aren't always something you have control over, e.g. I'm using WordPress and there are several notices coming out of the core. It's legitimate to want to suppress non-fatal errors.

Answer (score 11):

If you're on an Apache server, try setting the value in a .htaccess file. The general format is:

```
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /path/to/error.log
php_value error_reporting integer
```

where `integer` is the value you get from running something like:

```
echo E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE; // prints 30711
```

More info here:

http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/01/14/advanced-php-error-handling-via-htaccess/

Comment: Beware ! the code (like 30711) can differ on different PHP versions. It is best to check the echo on the sever itself, where you'll apply the config

Answer (score 5):

Try doing:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

The `error_reporting()` directive will always works (`PHP_INI_ALL`).

*Are you sure you're not including any library that changes your error reporting level?*

---

Do `error_reporting(0);` and then do this:

```
var_dump(error_reporting());
```

What is the output?

Comment: I've searched the entire project for "error_reporting" and it only shows a hit in the index.php file, and that's the error_reporting I added.  There's no occurrences of "set_error_handler", either.

Comment: @magenta: No `ini_set()` either?

Comment: var_dump outputs int(6135) which is E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE

Comment: There are two other ini_sets, but they set sendmail_from

Comment: 6135 = `E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR` + `E_USER_NOTICE` + `E_USER_WARNING` + `E_USER_ERROR` + `E_COMPILE_WARNING` + `E_COMPILE_ERROR` + `E_CORE_WARNING` + `E_CORE_ERROR` + `E_PARSE` + `E_WARNING` + `E_ERROR`. No `E_NOTICE` there.

Comment: @magenta: Do you have any `trigger_error()` function calls? Also, do notices still appear if you set `error_reporting(0);`?

Comment: No trigger_error and yep to error_reporting(0), it's like no matter what I do, it has no effect.

Comment: @magenta: Then I'm sorry but I can't think of anything else... Have you tried contacting your sysadmin / host provider?

Comment: That's next!  :)  Thanks everyone for your input, I do appreciate it, hopefully my ISP will be able to shed some light on this tomorrow.  I'm off to bed.

Comment: @magenta: In your question you mention "error_reporting 6143", that number says that you have all the constants above **plus** `E_NOTICE`. It might be a clue.

Comment: That is getting overridden by my var_dump mentioned above.  That gives me 6135, which is E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE according to a couple people at http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php (just do an inline search for 6135 and you'll find it)

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting Notice's or "USER" Notice's in your log?

To disable both use:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_USER_NOTICE);
```

Comment: Shows in the log as "PHP Notice"

Comment: I believe both are logged as "PHP Notice".  
You could search the phpcode for "trigger_error" or E_USER_NOTICE.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the error reporting level to something different

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php for more information

Comment: I tried that, too, including you variation - still getting logged.  Is there a way in php.ini to make ini_set() and error_reporting() NOT work?