# Migrating a PHP web application from a commercial server to local XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, xampp

I recently installed XAMPP on my local Windows 7 machine and migrated a PHP-intensive web application that was living on a commercial server.

It involved the following:

- Importing a sizable MySQL database
- Copying all of the `public_html` folder which included, obviously, many `PHP` scripts, `JavaScript`, `JQuery` and `CSS` files among other stuff

Every thing works fine on the local setup, **except** that *database results from `PHP` scripts* are not showing up in the webpages! I have:

- Changed the database configuration in the `PHP` to match the local database
- *Ensured* there are no database connection errors by running the scripts from the command prompt.
- Checked the `PHP` and `MySQL` logs for warnings and errors, but found none

Still see only the HTML page exactly as on the commercial server, except no database data.

Been perplexed for almost a day now. Any pointers please?

Comment: Have you got error reporting on? If so what are the errors?

Comment: @PhpDude, yes. But there are no warnings / errors. Just Notices.

Comment: From your local PHP, when you get the results from a db call, could you try `var_dump($queryResults); die();` then reload the page to see if there is any result set from mysql? You could also enable mysql's query log locally to see if mysql is actually running any queries. `SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html

Comment: Not surprised if this question is voted to close. The question is so broad. It could be any number of things. We don't know what if any frameworks are used, how you connect to the database, whether mysql is actually being connected to or anything. If you are able to narrow it down a bit, then maybe we could be more helpful in assisting.

Comment: @Gravy I agree, it sounds like a major migration so its not a case of saying 'oh this could be it' the fact your moving it to XAMPP could be the actual problem as the php version might be different etc etc the list goes on.

Comment: @Gravy and PhpDude, thanks much for looking in and the advice. After seeing my answer, you'll hopefully agree that _this was it!_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flummoxed by the fix, but eventually solved it. Here's the remedy trail, hope it helps someone in similar situations.

The `PHP` log file was flooded with irritating Notices that I wanted to not be logged. Followed [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099147/how-to-stop-php-from-logging-php-notice-errors/2099216#2099216) and included the following line in the `php.ini` file:

```
error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Lo and behold, database results started showing up in the HTMLs and the notices stopped getting logged in the log file. The local web app transformed exactly into the one living on the commercial server, completing the migration!

Answer (score 0):

You try new database name in phpMyAdmin, copy all other from export file, table etc, and use host=localhost, username=root and password=""

Comment: Thanks, @Ivica Kartelo! Please see my answer above.